# VBA Excel - Cells Slow to Merge - Multiple Columns on Multiple Sheets

Tags: vba, excel

The code below merges cells in multiple columns on multiple sheets, and it's SLOW!!!!

I'm hoping for any help at all to speed this up.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to get around the fact that the cells must be merged.

I broke up the for statements - it helped a bit, but it's still very, very slow.

Novice here. Be gentle :) Thank you!!! Cheryl

```
Function MergeCells()

    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ShName As String

    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    PIS.Activate

    For i = 1 To WS_Count
        Select Case ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name
            Case "Med Curr", "Med Ren", "Med RevRen", "Med Prop", "Med Renewal Alts A", "Med Renewal Alts B", _
                "Med Renewal Alts C", "Med Prop Other Markets 1A", "Med Prop Other Markets 1B", "Med Prop Other Markets 1C", _
                "Med Prop Other Markets 2A", "Med Prop Other Markets 2B", "Med Prop Other Markets 2C", _
                "Med Prop Other Markets 3A", "Med Prop Other Markets 3B", "Med Prop Other Markets 3C"
                    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Activate
                    ShName = ActiveSheet.Name
                    MergeCellsx (ShName)
        End Select
    Next i

End Function

Function MergeCellsx(ShName)

    Dim RngB As Range
    Dim row As Integer

    With Sheets(ShName)
        For row = 6 To 12
            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 2), .Cells(row, 3))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 5), .Cells(row, 6))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 8), .Cells(row, 9))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

        Next row
        For row = 14 To 18
            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 2), .Cells(row, 3))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 5), .Cells(row, 6))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 8), .Cells(row, 9))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

        Next row
        For row = 20 To 22
            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 2), .Cells(row, 3))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 5), .Cells(row, 6))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 8), .Cells(row, 9))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

        Next row
        For row = 24 To 25
            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 2), .Cells(row, 3))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 5), .Cells(row, 6))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 8), .Cells(row, 9))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

        Next row
        For row = 27 To 34
            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 2), .Cells(row, 3))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 5), .Cells(row, 6))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 8), .Cells(row, 9))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

        Next row
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: If your code works and you need help optimizing then this question is too broad for the forum and belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should change your function to a sub but apart from that if you absolutely must merge these cells I don't see how your code could be any more efficient, it's pretty tidy already. Consider if they really do have to be merged.